# How can I check the permissions of a network drive on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, fileshare

I have some file shares which had problems with the permissions in the past. I need to monitor them now, daily.

For this, I wanted to build a script in Python which automates that for me.

I can't get it working. And I don't know why and can't find a solution for it.

```
import os

paths = [r'\\10.0.0.0\Share$', r'\\10.0.0.1\Share$']

for path in paths:
    print os.access(path, os.R_OK)
```

This returns True for both, but if I open them in the explorer, I can't connect to them because I don't have the rights. Both should return False.

I am also open for other solutions than os.access()

Comment: On Windows, `os.access(path, os.R_OK)` is bogus; it only checks whether the current user is granted the right to read the file's attributes, which is implicitly true if the user has the right to list the parent directory.

Comment: To really check for read access on a network share, first get the share's security descriptor via `GetNamedSecurityInfo`. The object type is `SE_LMSHARE`. Then pass the security descriptor and desired access to `AccessCheck`. You'll need an impersonation token, such as from `OpenProcessToken` followed by `DuplicateToken`. You can do this via ctypes only or ctypes plus PyWin32. You need ctypes to call `AccessCheck`.